# Nested for loop is not completing the sequence I'm trying to print

Tags: java, for-loop

This is the nested for loop I have written:

```
int i,j;        
for(i=5;i>=1;i=i-1)
{
    for(j=1;j<i+1;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(i);
    }           
}
```

the above code prints: 555554444333221 but I'm trying to get it to add another '2' on the end, so it should print  5555544443332212.

I've spent a while changing the operators and the numbers but I haven't managed to figure it out yet.

Comment: Simple but key question: why should `2` be added?

Comment: Why can't you add a print(2) at the end?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? It's trivial to just add a `print` statement after the loops are finished, so you must some other intention than just printing `2`.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? Can you show some code that didn't work, and why the output was not correct? This could help us figure out what you're trying to do, and would also show effort on your part.

Answer (score 4):

Just add `System.out.print(2)` after the outer loop:

```
for(i=5;i>=1;i=i-1) {
    for(j=1;j<i+1;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
System.out.print(2);
```

As a side note, you can define `i` and `j` inside the `for` definitions:

```
for(int i=5;i>=1;i=i-1) {
    for(int j=1;j<i+1;j++) {
```

Comment: Really looks like sarcasms... ;)

Comment: I can't help it, that's what was asked and this is the correct answer.

Comment: i know it produces the correct answer but is there anyway the 'for' loop can be altered to get the same result? cheers for the help anyway

Comment: I can't think of any "pretty" way. Of course, you could add an `if` statement to check if you're on the last iteration of the loop and print the `2` if so, but that kind of defeats the whole purpose. What exactly is the purpose of that `2`, anyway?

Comment: @user3018244 If you have any specific number to print at very end then you can initialize two `ints` in `for` loop. and using some `if` condition you can print that `int` value. Something like `for(int j=1, y = 2;j<i+1;j++)`.

Answer (score 1):

simply just print a 2 at the end of for loop

```
for(i=5;i>=1;i=i-1) {
    for(j=1;j<i+1;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
System.out.print(2);
```